# matlab - Error using ./ Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab

Why am i getting this error?

In this program I want to get a linear regression. Next, I want to remove outlier data. Then, outliers are colored red, and normal points colored blue, the fitting line is colored green.
In this program in end command occurs an error. Can someone help me understand why?

```
x=[-0.05623  -0.20968   0.192102  0.992332  0.576244  1.305784 ...
   -0.72931  -0.86457  -0.09492   1.383214  1.303681 -0.12581  ...
   -0.59687  -1.52065   0.671842  0.022844 -1.17779  -0.33458  ...
   -1.82946   0.42999  -0.17399   1.631242 -1.35943   0.970507 ...
    0.14364   0.082604  0.716664  1.193484 -1.07106   1.318902 ...
   -1.21     -1.07411  -0.67256   0.736462 -1.06996   0.334715 ...
    0.411883  0.15412   0.554571 -1.17285   1.007587  0.11352  ...
    0.730051 -0.98351   0.052032  0.877599  1.014141 -0.08435  ...
   -1.85353  -1.09682   0.218628  0.794246  0.463124 -0.61263  ...
    2.2444    0.072348  0.865514 -0.4157   -1.11494   0.685252 ...
    1.037673  1.822212 -0.52899  -1.62797   1.617302  0.264137 ...
   -1.12715  -0.55918  -0.80885   1.161004  0.592105  0.242748 ...
    0.240477 -0.8215    0.993112  0.346395 -0.26113  -0.18471  ...
   -0.10173  -0.88704   0.741377  1.392208  2.4739    0.503919 ...
   -0.82248   0.200982 -1.00705  -0.61317  -0.65896  -0.83323  ...
    0.378179 -1.11534   0.667241  0.795333  1.037492 -0.02043  ...
    0.618953  1.803064  0.052993 -0.17789];

y=[5.436978 3.947596 5.153861 7.203315 5.725703 6.793873 3.545316 3.936359 ...
   4.237048 6.839705 7.122279 4.810857 4.288197 2.756219 6.208018 4.655615 ...
   3.29746  4.037378 2.486194 5.55364  4.931752 7.288785 3.057518 6.765781 ...
   4.633195 4.574674 5.536068 7.039812 3.51258  6.771749 3.625891 3.429356 ...
   3.524448 5.804945 2.987637 5.782922 5.441024 4.886507 5.662118 2.994722 ...
   6.762253 5.310672 6.183994 3.647019 5.090687 6.037325 6.680508 4.631969 ...
   1.904436 3.03886  5.583692 6.479913 5.177385 4.037497 8.4407   4.928997 ...
   6.522089 4.451288 3.282642 5.863934 6.755633 7.983111 4.344549 2.487526 ...
   7.696832 5.129475 3.351763 4.571945 3.730939 6.493319 6.459757 5.291498 ...
   5.490604 3.531393 6.574259 5.65695  4.609641 4.81884  5.201688 3.25646  ...
   6.172526 6.502666 8.719206 6.323678 4.043084 5.299436 3.389938 4.235615 ...
   4.322408 3.754491 6.042199 3.087029 5.413286 5.972943 6.497619 4.859718 ...
   5.679203 8.097901 4.604103 4.588513];

n=1  

p=polyfit(x,y,n);

a=p(1); b=p(2);

ymodel=a*x+b; 

plot(x,y,'o',x,ymodel);

all_idx = 1:length(x);
outlier_idx = abs(x -median(x)) > 2*std(x) | abs(y - median(y)) > 2*std(y)

x(outlier_idx) = interp1(all_idx(~outlier_idx), ...
                         x(~outlier_idx), all_idx(outlier_idx));

y(outlier_idx) =interp1(all_idx(~outlier_idx), ...
                        y(~outlier_idx), all_idx(outlier_idx));

x_out_ind = find(outlier_idx); % gives the index of outliers

% the next line gives an error: matrix dimensions must agree:
x_normal_ind = find(ones(1,00)-x_out_ind); % gives the index of normal

for i=x_normal_ind

    % this plot command gives an error:
    plot(x(i),y(i),'o','blue')
    hold on

end

for i=x_out_ind

    % this plot command gives an error:
    plot(x(i),y(i),'o','red')
    hold on

end

plot(x,a*x+b,'green')
```

Comment: i have in program should remove outliear

Comment: hi,i dont understand your purpose.please introuduce agin

Comment: i format my code,please help me

Comment: Please review my edit carefully. This is what I had initially in mind, when I asked for a copy/paste formatting.

Comment: yes,it is correct, sc

Comment: I DONOT   find any solutions

Comment: Have you examined the answer given by Adrian?

Answer (score 1):

First error is because ones(1,00) will return an empty matrix which is not the same size as x_out_ind i.e. matrix dimensions do not agree.

Second error is because you have supplied two strings to the plot command. This is often treated as a 'property':'value' pairing. So it is saying that the property 'o' is not valid.

I'd suggest using 'dbstop if error' and track down the errors one at a time.

Comment: what is your soultion in  2 The error command 
???????????
How do I fix error The instruction?

help me

Comment: Sorry I don't provide spoon fed solutions - rather try to guide so that you can fix the problems yourself. My solution would be to make the size of ones() the same as x_out_ind. That and the solution to the plot error can be found in the MATLAB documentation.

Comment: @user3429158 I agree with Adrian: approach this one error at a time. Familiarize yourself with the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/) and with the outline provided by Adrian you should be able to take it from here.